# Pattern to implement different storage strategies

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am going to implement **Data Mapper** pattern to store data in different storages/databases.

What is the best OOP pattern to implement this concept?

For example, I have `User` model class

```
public class User 
{
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String surname;

  /* getters, setters and model-level business logic  */
}
```

and appropriate Data Mapper class

```
public class UserMapper
{
  public User findById(int id)
  {
    // perform query to MySQL, Redis or another DB
  }

  /* other methods */
}
```

Is it a good idea to use **Strategy** pattern by creating multiple storage strategy classes and then inject them into DataMapper class?

```
 public class UserMySQLStorageStrategy extends UserStorageStrategy
 {
   public User findById(int id)
   {
     // perform query to MySQL
   }
 }

 public class UserRedisStorageStrategy extends UserStorageStrategy
 {
   public User findById(int id)
   {
     // perform query to Redis
   }
 }

public class UserMapper
{
  protected UserStorageStrategy _storageStrategy;

  public UserMapper(UserStorageStrategy storageStrategy)
  {
    this._storageStrategy = storageStrategy;
  }


  public User findById(int id)
  {
    return this._storageStrategy.findById(id);
  }

  /* other methods */
}
```

Comment: Just a warning -- the use of "best" in your question could attract close votes for "primarily opinion-based"

Comment: seems fine to me. I would call it UserDAO instead of UserMapper though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strategy looks awfully like the mapper class, itself. It may make sense to make your mapper and user objects into interfaces, instead, and then your specific implementations  choose how/where to store them. The strategy approach makes sense if your UserMapper class does many operations that are also unrelated to storage and that do not need to change despite the difference in storage; but if all your UserMapper class does is the storage, then an interface and multiple implementations would be simpler.

Comment: Yes, I understand it, so I have just deleted my comments just before you answered on them. :)

Comment: In the strategy approach case you described (if there are many operations that are also unrelated to storage), is it possible just to carry these unrelated to storage functions out to the base class?

Comment: @zavg it's better to use composition/delegation rather than inheritance. So, if there are many operations unrelated to storage, then your initial approach of providing a strategy would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any particular OOP Design Pattern. What you require is a interface that provide the functionality.

Then your different data storage should implement it. And then you just need a strategy that provide the expected instance for the work flow of your program.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make `UserMapper` an interface with multiple implementation concrete classes first and call the interface UserDao.

I'd call the implementation classes `User{Mysql|Redis|etc}DAO`. If you find any common piece of code between them it could be extracted into a common abstract base class.

At that point the logic of `UserMapper` class could be called to `UserDaoResolver`, that chooses and returns the concrete implementation upon some input or if you use some dependency injection framework (like Spring) you can delegate that function to it.

The current `UserMapper` caller would use the DAO implementation through its interface and obtain it by one of the method mentioned above.